# PHP Predis: how to get/delete keys containing special characters?

Tags: php, predis

I need to delete a key containing some special keys (in my case square brackets):

I do the following, but it does not work:

```
$this->redis;    
$keys = $this->redis->keys("*");
foreach ($keys as $key) {

    // keys are in the following format:   
    //    vir3_data_cache[zones_cdc_shifting_series_2013_5][1]

    $this->redis->del($key);
    // no key was deleted
}
```

I also tried to quote the key, but without success:

```
$this->redis;    
$keys = $this->redis->keys("*");
foreach ($keys as $key) {

    // keys are in the following format:   
    //    vir3_data_cache[zones_cdc_shifting_series_2013_5][1]

    $quotedKey = addslashes(addslashes($key));
    $this->redis->del($quotedKey);
    // no key was deleted
}
```

Comment: I don't see a different in these.

Comment: thanks @nmallare I just corrected the second block

Comment: Try wrapping your key in `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: @nmallare as you suggested, I tried to do `$this->redis->del("'vir3_data_cache[zones_cdc_shifting_series_2013_5][1]'")` but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**. The problem was related to the fact that predis insert automatically a configured prefix at the beginning of each key (in my case 'vir3_data_cache') before doing any operation. But the `keys("*")` command does not strip off the prefix from the key.

So I need to do the following in order to make my code work:

```
$prefix = $this->redis->getOptions()->__get('prefix')->getPrefix();

$keys = $this->redis->keys("*");
$removed = 0;
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (substr($key, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
        $key = substr($key, strlen($prefix));
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `phpredis`, you can get the prefix and delete a pattern of keys that way :

```
<?php
...

$prefix = $redisClient->getOption(Redis::OPT_PREFIX);
$redisClient->delete(array_map(
    function ($key) use ($prefix) {
        return str_replace($prefix, '', $key);
    }, $redisClient->keys('*'))
);
```